# How firebase cloud messaging [FCM] or any messaging service connects our mobiles?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am not looking for tutorial of FCM, I alway wonder how server push the message to mobile,

Normally mobile connects to server using DOMAIN(Public IP) with port number where our apache or any other server is running.

But not sure how server connects to our mobile devices ? Do each mobile device works as a small server running on its own public IP ?

Comment: The device reaches out to the server to get new messages, not the other way around.

Comment: Thats Pulling, here why it called push notification ?

Comment: That's because the decision to send comes from the server.  It's not possible for a server to reach out to a mobile device directly, as there are not enough dedicated IP addresses in the world for each device to have their own unique IP address that never changes.  Also it would be a pretty big security hole for any backend to simply reach out to a device.  Also, it would be really bad if devices had to use battery to stay awake in order to receive an incoming message.

Comment: Lastly, I can tell you for a fact that Firebase Cloud Message on Android requires that Play Services manage the socket connection to Google servers in order to receive the notification.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Very helpful details